# Mailgun laravel 4.2 change version "v2" to "v3"

Tags: laravel, mailgun

I'm working with Laravel 4.2 and Mailgun.

The base url of the api of mailgun changed, now it's `https://api.mailgun.net/v3/.........`.

When I perform a request with Laravel it looks like : `https://api.mailgun.net/v2/.........`

I checked the Facade who handle that :

```
// vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Mail/Transport/MailgunTransport.php
/**
 * Set the domain being used by the transport.
 *
 * @param  string  $domain
 * @return void
 */
public function setDomain($domain)
{
    $this->url = 'https://api.mailgun.net/v2/'.$domain.'/messages.mime';

    return $this->domain = $domain;
}
```

The version is hardcoded ... How I can change that properly ?

Answer (score 0):

Laravel 4.2 was build with mailgun v2. You could probably change v2 to v3 in the code and it would probably work since v3 of mailgun is backwards compatible. (http://blog.mailgun.com/default-api-version-now-v3/) But its not the nicest solution.

You could use an external dependancy like https://github.com/Bogardo/Mailgun that uses mailgun v3 api.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest making a code change to the code for the class with the problem, and submitting it back to Laravel's Github as a pull request.

I agree with you that it looks totally hard coded and can't be changed other than doing this, so that seems to be your best bet.

One thing to beware of though: I don't know the mailgun API, but if it's gone from v2 to v3, that implies there have been some breaking changes to the API, so don't think you can just change the number '2' into a '3' and expect it to work; you'll probably also need to change the code that makes the relevant API calls.

Comment: Just checked the API of mailgun, they are smart, you can still use the API without problems ;) (Still doesn't work with my mail config, but i will go ahead and see what's happening there)